# Turning a data.frame into a list of smaller data.frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Suppose I have a data.frame like [**THIS**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/m.csv) (*or see my code below*). As you can see, after every some number of continuous rows, there is a row with all `NA`s.

I was wondering how I could `split` [**THIS**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/m.csv) data.frame based on every row of `NA`?

For example, in my code below, I want my original data.frame to be `split` into 3 smaller data.frames as there are 2 rows of `NA`s in the original data.frame.

Here is is what I tried with no success:

```
## The original data.frame:
DF <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/m.csv", header = T) 

## the index number of rows with "NA"s; Here rows 7 and 14:
b <- as.numeric(rownames(DF[!complete.cases(DF), ])) 

## split DF by rows that have "NA"s; that is rows 7 and 14:
split(DF, b)
```

Comment: You can use `split(DF, DF$study_name)` after removing the NA rows with `DF <- na.omit(DF)`

Comment: Did you meant to include the NA row as well for the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we also need the NA rows, create a group with `cumsum` on the 'study.name' column which is blank (or `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   group_split(grp = cumsum(lag(study.name == "", default = FALSE)), keep = FALSE)
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
split(DF, cumsum(c(FALSE, head(DF$study.name == "", -1))))
```

Or with `NA`

```
i1 <- rowSums(is.na(DF))== ncol(DF)
split(DF, cumsum(c(FALSE, head(i1, -1))))
```

---

Or based on 'b'

```
DF1 <- DF[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(DF)), b), ]
split(DF1, as.character(DF1$study.name))
```

Comment: @Reza If I read your dataset, all the columns are not NA, some are blank as well

Comment: @Reza I updated the post with an option based on 'b'

Comment: Great, thanks. So, now it doesn't matter whether the `study.name` column is fully filled out or not, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can find occurrence of `b` in sequence of rows in `DF` and use `cumsum` to create groups.

```
split(DF, cumsum(seq_len(nrow(DF)) %in% b))
```